# Command parameter to void from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid with several columns. One of them is the idObiektu. I would like to pass idObiektu (from the selected row) as a parameter of command

In View i have

```
<Button Content="Usun" Command="{Binding UsunCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding idObiektu}" />

<DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Identyfikator" Binding="{Binding idObiektu}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nazwa obiektu" Binding="{Binding Nazwa}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adres" Binding="{Binding Adres}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pojemność obiektu" Binding="{Binding Pojemnosc}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Osoba kontakotwa" Binding="{Binding OsobaKontaktowa}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Numer telefonu" Binding="{Binding Telefon}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adres email" Binding="{Binding Email}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notatki" Binding="{Binding Notatki}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

In View model i have

```
public string idObiektu
        {
            get
            {
                return _idObiektu;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_idObiektu != value)
                {
                    _idObiektu = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(() => idObiektu);
                }

            }
        }

public ICommand UsunCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<string>(OnEdit); } }

        private void OnEdit(string itemToEdit)
        {

                int idObiektu = Int32.Parse(itemToEdit);
                atmaEntites.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Obiekty SET stan = '2' WHERE idObiektu = " + idObiektu + ";");
        }
```

I have problem, since every time **itemToEdit** is null

I try change VievModel to this, and **test string o is NULL**

```
public ICommand UsunCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<object>(OnEdit); } }

        private void OnEdit(object itemToEdit)
        {
            string o = itemToEdit.ToString();
            if (itemToEdit is null)
            {
                string idObiektu = itemToEdit.ToString(); ;
                atmaEntites.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Obiekty SET stan = '2' WHERE idObiektu = " + idObiektu + ";");
            }
            else
            {
                string idObiektu = itemToEdit.ToString(); ;
                atmaEntites.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Obiekty SET stan = '2' WHERE idObiektu = " + idObiektu + ";");
            }
        }
```

Comment: The Binding uses lowercase `Binding idObiektu`, while the property name is uppercase `IdObiektu`. You should have seen data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio.

Comment: You didn't pass `itemToEdit` value to `RelayCommand`

Comment: @Pavel it is `RelayCommand<string>` , hence the command parameter is converted to string and passed to the execute delegate automatically.

Comment: @Clemens i try with IdObiektu but it still doesn't work

Comment: But IdObiektu and UsunCommand are both properties of the same object, e.g. an instance of the row item class? You need to add more details to the question.

Comment: I add more details to question

Comment: So what about my question? Are both properties of the same object or not?

Comment: Yes, i fix that, but return NULL

Comment: Please don't edit you question with a solution. Post an answer instead.

Comment: @Clemens i don't have binding error in output, but return NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view I changed the CommandParameter Binding to

```
<Button Content="Usun" Command="{Binding UsunCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=dataGrid}"/>
```

In the view model I changed the object type to the item type in the DataGrid

```
public ICommand UsunCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<ObiektyForAllViews>(OnEdit); } }

private void OnEdit(ObiektyForAllViews itemToEdit)
{
    int idObiektu = itemToEdit.idObiektu;
    atmaEntites.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Obiekty SET stan = '2' WHERE idObiektu = " + idObiektu + ";");
}
```

Comment: You may also consider to add a property to your view model that holds the selected item. Then the DataGrid would be bound with `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObiektyForAllViews}"` and the Button with `CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedObiektyForAllViews.idObierektu}"` - where you could revert to `RelayCommand<string>` or `RelayCommand<int>` depending on the type you actually want to use for idObierektu. Certainly int would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

New answer... after re-reading the post and still not getting anywhere, I found what is up.  You mentioned you wanted the ID value from the selected row which did not previously trigger my mindset.  Here is what I believe you have and what is needed.

In order to get your list of records displayed in your screen, you probably have something like

```
public List<YourRecordDataClassStructure> MyListOfNames {get; set;}
```

Then, somewhere within your form, you are populating that list of records as queried from the database.

Since your post did not show the

```
<DataGrid . . . >
```

component of the view, I can only assume that it was something like

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding MyListOfNames} >
```

Next step... Create a new bindable property on your view model to represent a SINGLE instance of your data structure to bind to for the "SelectedItem" as chosen from the grid... something like

```
public YourRecordDataClassStructure JustOneItem {get; set;}
```

and update your DataGrid binding as

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding MyListOfNames} 
      SelectedItem={Binding JustOneItem} >
```

So now your form has a grid bound to your list of records.  It ALSO will update, when any record is selected from the datagrid, put a copy of the current record into the "JustOneItem" property on the view model.

Now, you can ignore the parameter and object type as string as the view model actually has the entire record and can grab any/all values from it by updating the body of the method

```
private void OnEdit(string itemToEdit)
{
   // confirm the selected object from the DataGrid was bound and actually selected.
   // if not, get out.
   if (JustOneItem== null || JustOneItem.MyIdColumn == 0)
      return;

   // we now have the entire object, get the ID column directly from 
   // the entire record displayed
   var idObiektu = JustOneItem.idObiektu;

   atmaEntites.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Obiekty SET stan = '2' WHERE idObiektu = " + idObiektu + ";");
}
```

So, the first step in the button relay command, I am explicitly pre-checking IF there was a record selected from the grid.  If nothing, get out... Also, ignore if the record's ID value was 0 as you probably would not even have a record in the list without an ID to be updated.

HTH